# When should I use unordered_map and not std::map

Tags: c++, hashmap

I'm wondering in which case I should use unordered_map instead of std::map.

I have to use unorderd_map each time  I don't pay attention of order of element in the map ?

Answer (score 23):

### `map`

1. Usually implemented using [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).
2. Elements are sorted.
3. Relatively small memory usage (doesn't need additional memory for the hash-table).
4. Relatively fast lookup: O(log N).

### `unordered_map`

1. Usually implemented using [hash-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).
2. Elements are not sorted.
3. Requires additional memory to keep the hash-table.
4. Fast lookup O(1), but constant time depends on the [hash-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) which could be relatively slow. Also keep in mind that you could meet with the [Birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: What does the hash table use the memory for? Isn't it just a hash function?
So for my understanding: memory of hash map = memory of map = O(n)

Comment: @ZakariaJaiathe consider you have a hash function that has an int16 as a return type. So you need a table with 2^16 elements in it, because you need to map the function output to the elements. Independently of how many real elements you have in your container you need a memory for the placeholders. There's a trick with using a so called pre-hash function to reduce the field of the mapped values, but it requires the more characters to describe it in details then a comment allows

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you can write it on multiple comments or if you have some useful link.

Comment: I don't understand how lookup can be O(1).. Theta(1) makes more sense where the number of buckets is sufficiently close to N, but the worst case complexity for a lookup should always be O(N/c) where c (constant) is the number of buckets which simplifies to O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Compare hash table (`undorded_map`) vs. binary tree (`map`), remember your CS classes and adjust accordingly.

The hash map usually has O(1) on lookups, the map has O(logN). It can be a real difference if you need many fast lookups.

The map keeps the order of the elements, which is also useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

`map` allows to iterate over the elements in a sorted way, but `unordered_map` does not.
So use the `std::map` when you need to iterate across items in the map in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you'd choose one over the other is performance.  Otherwise they'd only have created `std::map`, since it does more for you :)

Use `std::map` when you need elements to automatically be sorted.  Use `std::unordered_map` other times.

See [the SGI STL Complexity Specifications rationale](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/complexity.html).

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_map` is O(1) but quite high constant overhead for lookup, insertion, and deletion. `map` is O(log(n)), so pick the complexity that best suits your needs. In addition, not all keys can be placed into both kinds of map.